# I want to specify twiml instead of url in twilio functions

Tags: node.js

I want to define what to talk in twiml with twilio Functions.
It seems that the sample code below can be executed with twiml, but it actually fails.
Please let me know if it is not possible to specify in twiml.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/make-a-call

Make an outbound call

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  // The pre-initialized Twilio Client is available from the `context` object
  const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();

  // Query parameters or values sent in a POST body can be accessed from `event`
  const from = event.From || '+15017122661';
  const to = event.To || '+15558675310';
  // Note that TwiML can be hosted at a URL and accessed by Twilio
  const url = event.Url || 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml';

  // Use `calls.create` to place a phone call. Be sure to chain with `then`
  // and `catch` to properly handle the promise and call `callback` _after_ the
  // call is placed successfully!
  twilioClient.calls
    .create({ to, from, url })
    .then((call) => {
      console.log('Call successfully placed');
      console.log(call.sid);
      // Make sure to only call `callback` once everything is finished, and to pass
      // null as the first parameter to signal successful execution.
      return callback(null, `Success! Call SID: ${call.sid}`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      return callback(error);
    });
};
```

Execution result of the sample code
failure message

```
[RestException [Error]: Url parameter is required.] { status: 400, code: 21205, moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21205', detail: undefined } Error: Url parameter is required.
```

Comment: Please show the full code you used.

Comment: @CherryDT please can help with answer?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the `Url` parameter is missing. If you look closely, you'll see that you provided a parameter `url` (with lower-case `u`) but not `Url` (with upper-case `U`) as it was expected.

The solution is therefore to use the correct casing as it is described in the documentation (upper-case first letter): `Url`

The same issue exists in your code also for `To` and `From` which you incorrectly called `to` and `from`.